# comparing between date in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a stored procedure in mysql that doesnt work i need to compare a column that his name i get as parameter and a date that his value i allso get as parameter' my syntax is this.

---

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`vladiraheli`@`%` PROCEDURE sheepfarm.create_date_filter
( 
      in columnName VARCHAR(100), 
      in param varchar(100),
      in val varchar(100)
)
BEGIN

    declare formated_date  date;

    set formated_date = str_to_date(val,'%Y-%m-%d');

    set @stmt1 = concat(
     'select * from sheepfarm.Sheep where ' + 
      columnName + param  + 'formated_date') ;


    prepare stmt1 from @stmt1; 
    EXECUTE stmt1;

END $$
```

how can i make this work??

thank you vaery much for your help

Answer (score 0):

it has a problem with this statement:

```
set @stmt1 = concat('select * from sheepfarm.Sheep where ' + 
  columnName + param  + 'formated_date') ;
```

`formated_date` is passed as string, not as a variable.

```
set @stmt1 = concat('select * from sheepfarm.Sheep where ',  
  columnName, ' ', param, ' ', formated_date) ;
```

Since you are using `CONCAT`, you should use `comma` instead of `plus sign`.
Question, what are the possible values of `columnName`, `param` and `val`?